# Passing Thread ID to SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

**My two API calls are:**

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
  Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, _
                             ByVal lpfn As Long, _
                             ByVal hmod As Long, _
                             ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

**My Hook Keyboard function:**

```
Public Sub HookKeyboard()
    Dim ThreadID As Long
    ThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId

    KeyboardHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf KeyboardCallback, Application.Hinstance, ThreadID)

    Call HookedInitalize
End Sub
```

For some reason my hook is not catching. If I replace ThreadID with 0, indicating that the hook is to be system-wide, then the hook DOES catch. But when I try to limit it to just application wide, it does not catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is a ***global*** hook, so you *must* pass 0 as the thread ID. It won't work any other way.

You can see this in [the documentation for the `SetWindowsHookExA` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa); specifically, in [the Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#remarks), where it enumerates the hook types and their scopes.

Also of note: if you were to call `Err.LastDllError` after the attempt to call `SetWindowsHookEx` with a non-zero thread ID, you would have seen the error `ERROR_GLOBAL_ONLY_HOOK`, providing the same information.

Comment: duh not sure how i missed this. thank you for quick response & documentation! Excellent!